# SpringFramework: instantiation exception

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I'm new to Spring Framework so I decided to buy a book ("Spring in action" 3rd edition). Currently I'm at first chapter which covers basics - Dependency Injection (DI) and Aspect oriented programming (AOP).

I managed to run this code which showed DI.

***1#Interface implemented by knight***

```
package com.springinaction.knights;

public interface Knight {
  void embarkOnQuest() throws QuestException;
}
```

**1#Knight class**

```
package com.springinaction.knights;

public class BraveKnight implements Knight {
  private Quest quest;

  public BraveKnight(Quest quest) {
    this.quest = quest;       //<co id="co_injectedQuest"/>
  }

  public void embarkOnQuest() throws QuestException {
    quest.embark();
  }
}
```

**#2Quest interface**

```
package com.springinaction.knights;

public interface Quest {
  void embark() throws QuestException;
}
```

**#2Quest Exception**

```
package com.springinaction.knights;

public class QuestException extends RuntimeException {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

**#2Quest type class implementation**

```
package com.springinaction.knights;

public class SlayDragonQuest implements Quest {

  public void embark() throws QuestException {
    System.out.println("Slaying Dragon!");
  }

}
```

**#3Testing brave knight DI**

```
package com.springinaction.knights;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class KnightMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = 
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("knights.xml"); //<co id="co_loadKnightContext"/>

    Knight knight = (Knight) context.getBean("knight"); //<co id="co_getBeanKnight"/>

    knight.embarkOnQuest();//<co id="co_useKnight"/>
  }
}
```

**This is XML application context which injects quest into knight**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="quest" class="com.springinaction.knights.SlayDragonQuest" /><!--<co 
        id="co_quest_bean"/> -->

    <bean id="knight" class="com.springinaction.knights.BraveKnight">
        <constructor-arg ref="quest" /> <!--<co id="co_inject_quest_bean"/> -->
    </bean>

</beans>
```

***To this moment everything works, but when author wants to show AOP then something is wrong in XML file. The idea is that minstrel sings (logs) before knight goes on a quest and sings (logs off) when knight comes back from a quest.***

**Minstrel class**

```
package com.springinaction.knights;

public class Minstrel {
  public void singBeforeQuest() {     //<co id="co_singBefore"/>
    System.out.println("Fa la la; The knight is so brave!");
  }

  public void singAfterQuest() {     //<co id="co_singAfter"/>
    System.out.println(
            "Tee hee he; The brave knight did embark on a quest!");
  }
}
```

**XML AOP file, I guess there is some kind of error here, but I don't know what...**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd">

  <bean id="knight" class="com.springinaction.knights.BraveKnight">
    <constructor-arg ref="quest" />       
  </bean>

  <bean id="quest"
        class="com.springinaction.knights.SlayDragonQuest" />

  <bean id="minstrel" 
     class="com.springinaction.knights.Minstrel" /> <!--<co id="co_minstrel_bean"/>-->

  <aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="minstrel">

      <aop:pointcut id="embark" 
          expression="execution(* *.embarkOnQuest(..))" /> <!--<co id="co_define_pointcut"/>-->

      <aop:before pointcut-ref="embark"
                  method="singBeforeQuest"/>    <!--<co id="co_minstrel_before_advice"/>-->

      <aop:after pointcut-ref="embark"
                 method="singAfterQuest"/>     <!--<co id="co_minstrel_after_advice"/>-->

    </aop:aspect>
  </aop:config>  
</beans>
```

***Testing this looks exactly like in #3 Testing BraveKnight***

Exception which is verry long.

```
sie 20, 2013 3:06:58 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@14d5bc9: startup date [Tue Aug 20 15:06:58 CEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
sie 20, 2013 3:06:58 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [knights-aop.xml]
sie 20, 2013 3:06:58 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@46aa61: defining beans [knight,quest,minstrel,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#1,embark]; root of factory hierarchy
sie 20, 2013 3:06:58 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@46aa61: defining beans [knight,quest,minstrel,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#1,embark]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'knight' defined in class path resource [knights-aop.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'embark' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embark': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/BCException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:454)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.springinaction.knights.KnightAopMain.main(KnightAopMain.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'embark' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embark': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/BCException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:629)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:86)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:890)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'embark' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embark': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/BCException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:615)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embark': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/BCException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1007)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/BCException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1000)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.BCException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 48 more
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Download AspectJ and add `aspectjrt.jar` & `aspectjweaver.jar` to your classpath. Spring's aop config with the aop namespace is based on AspectJ, which is no more shipped bundled with org.springframework.aop jar.

Following is maven dependency in case its a maven based project

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Uhh! I had problems to import authors project into my Spring tool suite, so I decided to make my own project from his files and forgot about some dependencies. Thanks a million!